# Jasper Report - gmap PrimFaces

Tags: java, jasper-reports, gmaps4rails

Good afternoon, I have in my application a map of google, which was implemented using the gmap component of PrimeFaces. Would you like to know if there is a possibility of sending an image of this map to the Jasper Report?

Here is an example of the map:

```
<p:tab title="Mapa" closable="false">
    <p:gmap id="gmap"
        center="#{trajetoController.latitudeInicial} , 
        #{trajetoController.longitudeInicial}"
        zoom="10" type="HYBRID" style="width:100%;height:600px"
        model="#{trajetoController.rotaModel}">
    </p:gmap>
</p:tab>
```

Comment: `Would you like to know if there is a possibility of sending an image of this map to the Jasper Report?` - What do you mean? Do you have file with image of map (binary image)? You can use different image's types at report (jpg, png and so on)

Comment: No, actually I need an image of this map, I do not have this file. I need the map image to send to my report. But I can not find a solution to that.